# Testing node server with mocha and nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

I'm learning node and mocha and have the test below (production code increments a field in the database).

To see if its working, I'm outputting the value of this field before and after a call to /events (see the two console.log statements).

At the moment, the value output is 1 in both cases.  Outside of the test the code is working fine and the field is incremented.

I suspect its something to do with the callbacks in my test code (as I'm still learning about how to correctly write and test node code this is almost certainly the case).

Hopefully someone can spot the problem.  The production code this is testing is [here](https://gist.github.com/RobZolkos/91eda1bb6f67ae513204) (gist).

```
it('"processed" event increases processed count', function(done) {
  Edm.find({campaignguid: '1234'}).success(function(edm) {
    edmProcessedCount = edm.processed;
    console.log("pre: " + edmProcessedCount);  // result is 1

    request.post('http://localhost:3001/events?campaignguid=1234&event=processed', function(err, res, body) {
      Edm.find({campaignguid: '1234'}).success(function(edmm) {
        console.log("post : " + edmm.processed);  // result is 1 (should be 2)
        done();
      });
    })

  });
});
```

Comment: The code you post looks okay, apart from not checking `err` to see if an error occurred during `request.post()`. It might have to do with your implementation of the handler for `/events`, so it might be useful to post that as well.

Comment: I think you'll have to show the code for Edm.find as the edm and edmm arguments are just 2 seperate variables. There is nothing in the code at the moment to imply they are one and the same and are a counter.

Comment: @AndyD `Edm.find` is a Sequelize construct (`Edm` is the model, `find` the method to query the database).

Comment: @robertklep I've added a link to a gist showing the production code.  Edm.find is simply a Sequelize finder (not doing anything out of the ordinary).  Hopefully thats enough info.

Comment: @RobZolkos the [console.log](https://gist.github.com/RobZolkos/91eda1bb6f67ae513204#file-index-js-L17) shows that `processed` is incremented? Also, is there a difference between `.find({ where : { campaignguid : ... } })` and `.find({ campaignguid : ... })`? (I don't know Sequelize well enough)

Comment: @robertklep you found the problem.  The {where} clause was required.  Everything now works great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query in the Mocha test case is missing a `where` clause:

```
Edm.find({ where : { campaignguid: '1234' }})
           ^^^^^
```